# How to perform right shift on RISC

Tags: microprocessors, risc

I'd like to know how I can perform a right shift on a Reduced Instruction Set Computer that does not offer this operation on it's own.
A left shift can be simply done by adding a register to itself but how about a right shift?

The `RISC` offers only:

```
ADD 
NOT
NXOR (XOR)
AND (NAND)
```

so `OR` and `NOR` can all be emulated by several `(N)AND` and `NOT` operations.

Comment: Can it multiply by 2 or divide by 2 ?

Comment: Multiplication by two can be done, but that is left shift.
The RISC does not natively support division and algorithms for that are fairly complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C program below uses only authorized instructions plus conditional jumps, and it shifts `input` into `output` by 1.

If the instruction you are trying to emulate is “shift by n”, then you should start with `c` equal to 2<sup>n</sup>.

```
unsigned int shift_right(unsigned int input) {
  unsigned int d = 1;
  unsigned int output = 0;
  for (unsigned int c = 2; c <= 0x80000000; c += c)
  {
    if (c & input) 
      output |= d;
    d += d;
  }
  return output;
}
```